# hclust/dendrogram prune tree stack leaves

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

A dendrogram from `hclust` will have a starting branch for each leaf.  The `rect.hclust` function allows me to plot rectangles around clusters.  Is there a way to cut the tree at that point and have all the leaves as a list under that branch?

Example code:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(mtcars[1:10, ]), "ave")
plot(hc)
stats::rect.hclust(hc, 3)
```

Gives:

[image]

I'd like to get:

[image]

Comment: @jenesaisquoi It's the plot I'm after.

Comment: not perfect `hc <- hclust(dist(mtcars[1:10, ]), "ave"); cc <- cut(as.dendrogram(hc), 75); plot(cc$upper, leaflab = 'none'); sapply(seq_along(cc$lower), function(x) {xx <- c(1.5, 3.5, 7.7); y <- cc$lower[[x]];lbls <- rapply(y, function(z) attr(z, 'label')); text(xx[x], attr(y, 'height'), cex = .8, pos = 1, xpd = NA, paste0(lbls, collapse = '\n'))})`

Comment: @rawr that's it.  Can you throw down please

Comment: I can't get the x values though. I think those are calculated under the hood in the call to `graphics:::plotHclust` and this also seems to depend on what happens to the tree _after_ the position you wish to cut since you still have that large gap between the second and third branches